# On Excel, how can I tell which other worksheets dependents are on?

Tags: excel, dataset, ms-office, formula, spreadsheet

When I click "Trace Dependents" for a cell on a given worksheet and the little arrow picture shows that it has dependents on other worksheets in the workbook, how can I find out exactly which other cells of which other worksheets are dependents of the original cell?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for - double-click on an arrow and the list of all dependent cells & worksheets should pop-up -

[image]